# Which FAA regulations apply to the Stratolaunch?

Tags: faa-regulations, aircraft-certification, experimental-aircraft, stratolaunch

[image]
([Image source](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Stratolaunch-apogee.jpg))

Which FAA regulations apply to the [Stratolaunch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stratolaunch_Systems) being built by [Vulcan Aerospace and Scaled Composites](http://www.scaled.com/projects/stratolaunch)?

Do they follow the same regulations for the type cert, production and CofA (Certificate of Airworthiness) just like a commercial airplane built by Boeing?

Answer (score 4):

That would be under [Title 14 CFR, Chapters 400-460](http://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/text-idx?SID=1da47a72890e02b8acfa713f81c7b0a3&mc=true&tpl=/ecfrbrowse/Title14/14chapterIII.tpl).

A lot of this stuff really hasn't been finalized yet and these vehicles are considered only experimental and regulated similar to homebuilt aircraft.  Passengers are required to sign waivers advising them of their risk and that they understand this and hold the organization indemniable to any and all liabilities involved with using this system.

Comment: 400-600 apply to the space vehicle itself, the carrier aircraft probably falls under a different set of CFR's, probably the experimental category.

Comment: Well in the case of StratoLaunch it is unmanned - or at least the booster is.  One could consider the system a rocket launch from a flying launch pad.  In Re for the carrier aircraft, most likely considered an experimental category vehicle.

Comment: @ymb1 It's not a link-only answer (and wasn't at the time you made your most recent comment).